# Memory size error in laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pagination

When I try to select some field with join query with pagination it show en error like

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 45797376 bytes)`

My query is

```
$price_all = DB::table('model_price')
            ->join('operator_model','model_price.model_id','=','operator_model.id')
            ->join('operator_route','operator_model.operator_route_id','=','operator_route.id')
            ->join('route', 'operator_route.route_id', '=', 'route.id')
            ->join('operator', 'operator_route.operator_id', '=', 'operator.id')
            ->select('model_price.id', 'model_price.price', 'route.route_name', 'operator.operator_name')
            ->paginate(2);
```

In my database only 5 records are stored. it not big data.

when I try without pagination then it works fine. like

```
$price_all = DB::table('model_price')
                ->join('operator_model','model_price.model_id','=','operator_model.id')
                ->join('operator_route','operator_model.operator_route_id','=','operator_route.id')
                ->join('route', 'operator_route.route_id', '=', 'route.id')
                ->join('operator', 'operator_route.operator_id', '=', 'operator.id')
                ->select('model_price.id', 'model_price.price', 'route.route_name', 'operator.operator_name')
                ->get();
```

Now how can I optimize this query.

Comment: Could you please specify the code you're using in the `paginate()` case to access the `$price_all` variable inside your view?

Comment: I would recommend you install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar and then check the query log displayed. You could greatly improve your query by just calculating the count separating leaving out joins since you aren't using a where.  Then just create the pager using Paginator::make see docs

Answer (score 0):

Try using Offset & Limit instead of paginate.

```
$price_all = DB::table('model_price')
               ->join('operator_model','model_price.model_id','=','operator_model.id')
               ->join('operator_route','operator_model.operator_route_id','=','operator_route.id')
               ->join('route', 'operator_route.route_id', '=', 'route.id')
               ->join('operator', 'operator_route.operator_id', '=', 'operator.id')
               ->select('model_price.id', 'model_price.price', 'route.route_name', 'operator.operator_name')
               ->skip(0)
               ->take(2)
               ->get();
```